What are the units of equation 13 of Buckingham's 1960 paper about chemical shift influenced by electric field?
Has anyone read Buckingham's 1960 paper 'CHEMICAL SHIFTS IN THE NUCLEAR MAGNETIC RESONANCE SPECTRA OF MOLECULES CONTAINING POLAR GROUPS'? I'm having trouble understanding Equation 13 regarding the units of the electric field strength  and , so I can't apply this equation. Also, the dimensions of the shielding constant in Equation 12 are not equal to 1. Can anyone explain why this is? Please help.

Buckingham, A. D. CHEMICAL SHIFTS IN THE NUCLEAR MAGNETIC RESONANCE SPECTRA OF MOLECULES CONTAINING POLAR GROUPS. Can. J. Chem. 1960, 38, 300–307. doi 10.1139/v60-040 (open access).

Two lines earlier there is a statement reading

$\sigma^{(0)} = \pu{17.8E-6 e.s.u.}$

Later, there is note of

$E = \pu{10^5 e.s.u.}$

This is now cgs' system of units (i.e., defined by centimetre, gram, and second) and e.s.u. refers then to electrostatic units.  Statcoulomb is an other name of it.

And R in inverse centimeters which is not uncommon. I’m old enough that my undergraduate physics was in cgs- original Jackson etc.

Buttonwood, I think the OP is confused by the equation 13, the powers of E are confusing because it looks like a series expansion. A series expansion cannot have units.

@ACR Hm. Presuming eq. 13 as generally applicable (at least in the scope of the paper), then its mathematical relation to equations 18, e.g. $E(\ce{CH3}) = \pu{8.74E22 \mu}$ and $E^2_2 = \pu{82.8E44 µ^2}$ (p. 304, loc. cit.) and 19 (the later running without an explicit dimension) escape my current comprehension. How do you join the elements together here?

@EdV Though at a different scale of energy than your setups in optical spectroscopy, is the mathematics here an area you have experience?

@JonCuster It seems a bit «teaching new dogs old tricks» (Clegg, W. Some reflections on symmetry: pitfalls of automation and some illustrative examples. Acta Cryst. E 2019, 75, 1812–1819 (https://doi.org/10.1107/S2056989019014907, open access) cites the title of a microsymposium here) though «trick» might be more suitably replaced by «approach».

@Buttonwood Thank you very, very, very much! I think you are exactly right! This helps me a lot with my research.

Thanks to response of @Buttonwood, this paper used the CGS-ESU system of units for e (esu), a (cm), m (g), c (cm/s²), λ (esu), R (cm), and E (esu/cm²). The shielding constant would be dimensionless if using the CGS system of units. Below is the calculation code for σ(2), and the results match those in the literature:

